# Issue building polkadot-parachain binary

Tags: cumulus

I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong so any help is appreciated.

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch polkadot-v0.9.28 https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus.git
cd cumulus
cargo build --release --locked -p polkadot-parachain
```

gives me this error

```
error: There are multiple `polkadot-parachain` packages in your project, and the specification `polkadot-parachain` is ambiguous.
Please re-run this command with `-p <spec>` where `<spec>` is one of the following:
  polkadot-parachain@0.9.28
  polkadot-parachain@0.9.230
```

So I run with the former command

```
cargo build --release --locked -p polkadot-parachain@0.9.28
```

Compilation appears to be successful

```
...
Compiling frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.28#b4db7298)
   Compiling polkadot-parachain v0.9.28 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.28#314298c3)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 4m 13s
```

However, there is no polkadot-parachain binary in my release folder and the node can't run.All I have in my release folder are libpolkadot_parachain.d and libpolkadot_parachain.rlib libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for this information. I was able to replicate it as well.

I have filed an issue here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/1753

I recommend you compile using the following command which is noted here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus#local-setup

```
cargo build --release
```